# Make flask run honor app.debug

Tags: python, flask

I have a minimal application in `test_app/__init__.py`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
```

Now if I try to run it with `env FLASK_APP=test_app:app flask run`, I get this output:

```
 * Serving Flask app "test_app:app"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5001/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

(Note the line `Debug mode: off`)

However, if I create a `test_app/__main__.py` file with

```
from test_app import app

app.run()
```

I get the expected result:

```
 * Serving Flask app "test_app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: xxx-xxx-xxx
```

I also tried adding this to `__init__.py`:

```
class Config:
    DEBUG = True

app.config.from_object(Config)
```

The result is the same.

Adding the command line option `--debugger` for `flask run` also doesn’t seem to help.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make the CLI honor the `debug` value?

Using Flask 1.0.2, but the problem seems to be present in 0.12, too.

Comment: From the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Flask.debug) of `Flask.debug`: "It may not behave as expected if set in code."

Comment: I saw that, too. But it doesn’t even work if I set it on the command line.

Comment: The debugger will be off if the environment is "production". I guess this has priority over your settings.

Comment: That’s exactly what solved the problem; setting the environment to `development` did the trick.